Improve out of sample predictions XG boost/RF
I have a very extensive XGB Boost/RF, where the in-sample predictions are quite ok. Based on the validation set, it doesn't look overfit. If I make the actual predictions, the model is just taking one single value. The predictions are on a daily business days.
The correlation plot and the feature importance are showing that EMA_5_days is an important contributor. I have therefore used this variable for prediction. The model is also using a Monte Carlo Simulation method, but it still makes useless predictions.
I have to clue what to do next. Below you will find the complete code. Any help is welcome! It looks like the model doesn't know what to do. I also added the week days information in the model, so it could know which date is that to predict.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
import holidays

# Ensure DATE_TIME_STAMP is in datetime format and recompute datetime-related features
df_forecast['DATE_TIME_STAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_forecast['DATE_TIME_STAMP'])
df_forecast['DayOfWeek'] = df_forecast['DATE_TIME_STAMP'].dt.dayofweek
df_forecast['WeekOfYear'] = df_forecast['DATE_TIME_STAMP'].dt.isocalendar().week
df_forecast['MonthOfYear'] = df_forecast['DATE_TIME_STAMP'].dt.month

# Remove existing one-hot encoded columns if they exist to prevent duplicates
for col_prefix in ['DayOfWeek_', 'WeekOfYear_', 'MonthOfYear_']:
    df_forecast = df_forecast.loc[:, ~df_forecast.columns.str.startswith(col_prefix)]

# Perform one-hot encoding
df_forecast = pd.get_dummies(df_forecast, columns=['DayOfWeek', 'WeekOfYear', 'MonthOfYear'])

# Ensure no duplicate columns exist after encoding
assert not df_forecast.columns.duplicated().any(), "Duplicate columns found after processing."


param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [50, 100, 150],
    'max_depth': [4, 5, 6],
    'learning_rate': [0.05],
    'subsample': [0.8],
    'colsample_bytree': [0.8],
    'min_child_weight': [1],
    'gamma': [0.1],
    'lambda': [1],
    'alpha': [0.1]
}

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)

def update_ema(last_ema, new_value, alpha=0.1, historical_ema_weight=0.7):
    """
    Update the Exponential Moving Average (EMA) based on the last EMA value, the new incoming value, 
    the alpha parameter, and the historical EMA weight.
    
    :param last_ema: The last calculated EMA value.
    :param new_value: The new data point to be incorporated into the EMA.
    :param alpha: The smoothing factor applied to the new value, between 0 and 1.
    :param historical_ema_weight: The weight given to the historical EMA in the balance.
    :return: The updated EMA value.
    """
    # Calculate the contribution from the new value and the historical EMA
    new_value_contribution = alpha * new_value
    historical_ema_contribution = (1 - alpha) * historical_ema_weight * last_ema

    # The remaining weight to reach 1 is given to the last EMA
    remaining_weight = 1 - new_value_contribution - historical_ema_contribution

    return new_value_contribution + historical_ema_contribution + remaining_weight * last_ema


def prepare_features_for_prediction(base_features, model_features):
    prepared_features = {feature: base_features.get(feature, 0) for feature in model_features}
    return pd.DataFrame([prepared_features])

def naive_monte_carlo_simulation(models, base_features, num_simulations=100):
    simulated_predictions = []
    for _ in range(num_simulations):
        perturbed_features = {feature: max(0, value + np.random.normal(0, max(0.1 * abs(value), 0.01))) for feature, value in base_features.items()}
        prepared_features = pd.DataFrame([perturbed_features])
        prediction = predict_with_ensemble(models, prepared_features)
        simulated_predictions.append(prediction)
    return np.median(simulated_predictions)

def predict_with_ensemble(models, features):
    features = features[models['XGB'].get_booster().feature_names]
    pred_XGB = models['XGB'].predict(features)
    pred_RF = models['RF'].predict(features)
    return (pred_XGB + pred_RF) / 2

def predict_next_n_business_days(models, base_features, last_date, country_code, n_days=30, alpha_ema=0.1):
    future_predictions = []
    next_date = pd.to_datetime(last_date)
    try:
        country_holidays = holidays.CountryHoliday(country_code)
    except (KeyError, NotImplementedError):
        print(f"Holiday information for country code '{country_code}' not found or not implemented.")
        return []
    
    # Initialize the last EMA value
    last_ema_value = base_features.get('ema_5_days', 0)
    
    while len(future_predictions) < n_days:
        next_date += pd.Timedelta(days=1)
        if next_date.weekday() >= 5 or next_date in country_holidays:
            continue
        
        # Reset all one-hot encoded day, week, and month features to 0
        for i in range(7):
            base_features[f'DayOfWeek_{i}'] = 0
        base_features[f'DayOfWeek_{next_date.dayofweek}'] = 1
        
        for i in range(1, 54):
            base_features[f'WeekOfYear_{i}'] = 0
        if next_date.isocalendar().week in range(1, 54):
            base_features[f'WeekOfYear_{next_date.isocalendar().week}'] = 1
        
        for i in range(1, 13):
            base_features[f'MonthOfYear_{i}'] = 0
        base_features[f'MonthOfYear_{next_date.month}'] = 1
        
        # Use naive Monte Carlo simulation for prediction
        median_prediction = naive_monte_carlo_simulation(models, base_features, num_simulations=100)
        
        # Update the EMA with the median prediction
        last_ema_value = alpha_ema * median_prediction + (1 - alpha_ema) * last_ema_value
        base_features['ema_5_days'] = last_ema_value
        
        future_predictions.append({
            'DATE_TIME_STAMP': next_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
            'Forecast': max(0, median_prediction),  # Ensure forecast is not negative
            'SHIP_TO_COUNTRY': country_code
        })
    
    return future_predictions


# Main execution starts here
forecast_df_XGB = pd.DataFrame()
forecast_out_of_sample_df_XGB = pd.DataFrame()
validation_df_XGB = pd.DataFrame()
scores_list = []
error_log_list = []
models_dict = {}

for item_col in df_forecast.columns:
    if item_col.startswith('SHIP_TO_COUNTRY_'):
        country_code = item_col.split('_')[-1]
        df_country = df_forecast[df_forecast[item_col] == 1]
        
        if 'ema_5_days' not in df_country.columns or len(df_country) < 50:
            error_message = f"Skipping country code {country_code} due to insufficient data or missing 'ema_5_days' column."
            error_log_list.append({'Country_Code': country_code, 'Error': error_message})
            continue
        
        X = df_country.drop(['UNIQUE_ITEM_COUNT_COUNTRY', 'DATE_TIME_STAMP', item_col], axis=1)
        y = df_country['UNIQUE_ITEM_COUNT_COUNTRY']
        
        X_train_val, X_test, y_train_val, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
        X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train_val, y_train_val, test_size=0.25, shuffle=False)
        
        model_XGB = XGBRegressor()
        grid_search_XGB = GridSearchCV(model_XGB, param_grid, cv=tscv, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
        grid_search_XGB.fit(X_train, y_train)
        
        model_RF = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
        model_RF.fit(X_train, y_train)
        
        models_dict[country_code] = {'XGB': grid_search_XGB.best_estimator_, 'RF': model_RF}
        
        y_val_pred = predict_with_ensemble(models_dict[country_code], X_val)
        y_test_pred = predict_with_ensemble(models_dict[country_code], X_test)
        
        validation_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_val, y_val_pred))
        validation_mae = mean_absolute_error(y_val, y_val_pred)
        test_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_pred))
        test_mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_test_pred)
        
        scores_list.append({
            'Country_Code': country_code,
            'Validation_RMSE': validation_rmse,
            'Validation_MAE': validation_mae,
            'Test_RMSE': test_rmse,
            'Test_MAE': test_mae
        })
        
        test_forecast = pd.DataFrame({
            'DATE_TIME_STAMP': df_country.loc[X_test.index, 'DATE_TIME_STAMP'],
            'Forecast': np.maximum(y_test_pred, 0),
            'Actual': y_test,
            'SHIP_TO_COUNTRY': country_code
        })
        forecast_df_XGB = pd.concat([forecast_df_XGB, test_forecast], ignore_index=True)
        
        base_features = X_train_val.iloc[-1].to_dict()
        base_features['ema_5_days'] = update_ema(base_features.get('ema_5_days', 0), y_train_val.iloc[-1])
        
        last_prediction_date = df_country['DATE_TIME_STAMP'].max()
        out_of_sample_predictions = predict_next_n_business_days(models_dict[country_code], base_features, last_prediction_date, country_code, n_days=30)
        
        # After processing all countries, concatenate the out-of-sample predictions
        forecast_out_of_sample_df_XGB = pd.concat([forecast_out_of_sample_df_XGB, pd.DataFrame(out_of_sample_predictions)], ignore_index=True)


error_log_df = pd.DataFrame(error_log_list)
scores_df_XGB = pd.DataFrame(scores_list)

print("Validation Results:\n", validation_df_XGB.head())
print("Forecast Results:\n", forecast_df_XGB.head())
print("Out-of-Sample Forecast Results:\n", forecast_out_of_sample_df_XGB.head(30))
print("Accuracy Scores:\n", scores_df_XGB.head())
print("Error Log:\n", error_log_df.head())



Is using XGBoost a must?
As your problem sounds like a Time Series problem, I would suggesting reading about models from the ARIMA family, CNNs and LSTMs can also be used for Time Series.
Some examples can be found at:

https://www.kaggle.com/code/ritesh7355/develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting
https://neptune.ai/blog/arima-vs-prophet-vs-lstm
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-convolutional-neural-network-models-for-time-series-forecasting/


I tried ARIMA and HoltWinters, the outcomes were very poor. Will try if LSTM is a better fit.
